# Some tabs (Window) are black in the tabbar (and not able to close that window in macOS?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, spaces

I am using a MacBook Pro

Some Tabs (Window) are black and don't show anything (tabbar or anything) and I am not able to close that window?

[image: Show tabbar]

Does anyone else face the same issue?

Comment: Hi again! :) Those are Spaces, not tabs or windows. So, if you hover the mouse over one of those, you don't see an x button you can click to delete it?

Comment: Also holding down the Option key should help display the x button. See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8329062 for a case where someone had hundreds of these.

Comment: no.. I cant see close button on those black screen

Answer (score 0):

Hold ⌥option, hover the black screen preview and click the upper-left button to exit full screen.

Since there's no actual app there, this closes the space.

[image]

It's up to Apple to fix the bug in macOS that causes them in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

Try hitting the Esc (Escape) key. You may be accidentally in full-screen mode.

Comment: tried but no help